# What data are stored in TPM and is it safe to erase them?

Tags: firmware, tpm

I frequently use `fwupdmgr` (under Fedora 28) to upgrade the firmware of my DELL laptop and it works well. However I recently got the following error:

```
$ fwupdmgr get-updates
ignoring Latitude 7480 TPM 2.0 [54e80140e7d8cb6211a54dae2682399e653c0884] as not updatable
```

`fwupdmgr` is able to install other updates though.

AFAIU, TPM can't be updated if some information have been stored in it. There is an option in the BIOS to clear the data stored in TPM but I don't want to loose data.

I was wondering what are those data and if clearing them would allow me to upgrade.

In particular, I used the Machine Own Key infrastructure to be able to sign kernel modules (`virtualbox`). I guess those keys are stored in the TPM. If I erase the TPM data can I reinstall the same key with `mokutil` ?

As an aside, I discovered the problem because for quite some time, I have an error message when booting the laptop:

```
kernel: tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred attempting the self test
```

I was wondering if those 2 errors are linked (and so if updating the firmware would suppress the error).

Comment: You may have run into a kernel bug: https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/895585/

The two issues may well be related.

Comment: @mnistic: thanks for your answer. I'm not smart enough to understand the link you sent but do you know if this patch in merged into Fedora or vanilla kernel ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. That's probably a question for their forums / mailing lists.

Comment: I will ask them. Do you have any idea on the TPM data ?

Comment: The TPM can contain keys, system measurements and protected sensitive data. So it all depends on your system setup. As far as mokutil, if by mokutil you mean this thing: https://github.com/lcp/mokutil it doesn't seem to be using the TPM for anything. Fedora doesn't depend on it to boot (obviously) and I don't know if Dell puts anything in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleared the data in the bios. Nothing bad happened and `fwupdmgr` doesn't complain anymore. The log message at boot is still there however. Thanks to @mnistic.